# Succinct notation for specifying that eigenvalues must have negative real part?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, notation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a succinct way to denote that all eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ have negative real parts?

If the eigenvalues were real, I could simply write this as $$-1 < A < +1$$ since we have the standard definition of matrix inequality $$A < B \equiv x^\top A x < A^\top B x\ \ \forall x$$ but what about the case when the eigenvalues might be complex?

Comment: ${\rm spec}\; A \cap \{{\rm Re }\;z \geqslant 0\} = \emptyset$ ?

Comment: Maybe introduce the term "stable"? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix.

Comment: @chhro: Right, this is indeed in the context of stability, but I'm just looking for compact notation so I don't have to switch to English in the middle. :)

Comment: @Evgen: That confuses the reader (what's $z$?)

Comment: @Mehrdad My bad, is ${\rm spec} \; A \cap \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \colon \; {\rm Re} \; z \geqslant 0 \} = \emptyset$ better?

Comment: @Evgeny: Well, I think the most important part of your comment is the $\operatorname{spec}$ operator, which I've never seen in texts. Is this standard notation/could you point to a reference?

Comment: It seems to be that the standard notation for spectrum of linear operator $A$ is $\sigma (A)$, not ${\rm spec} \; A$ (however, I've seen it in some books). So it's better to use $\sigma (A)$. You can find the reference for this in Leslie Hogben's Handbook of linear algebra, for example.

Comment: @Evgeny: Ah, yeah. I've seen $\sigma(A)$ but had forgotten about it, so maybe I'll use that. Thanks :)